# How to read data from a specific column of excel having mixed data types in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a question. I have written a code in MATLAB to read  data from a specific column of a specific sheet of excel and put in `numdata_1`. Here is the code:

```
for i = 1:28
    i
    filename = 'All files.xlsx';
    sheet = i;
    xlRange = 'B:B';
    xlRange_2 = 'BO:BO';
    numdata_1 = xlsread (filename,sheet,xlRange);
    numdata_2 = xlsread (filename,sheet,xlRange_2) % (this column contains only numeric data)
```

There are 28 sheets in `All files.xlsx`. The problem is that I have 8 sheets where xlRange = 'B:B' is numeric data while 20 sheets where xlRange = 'B:B' is mixed (numeric + string/char). So, `numdata_2` can not read the char or string type data from xlRange = 'B:B' and is showing only numeric type data in 20 output sheets by this command in `pp.xlsx`:

```
xlswrite('pp.xlsx',numdata_1,sheet,'C3');
xlswrite('pp.xlsx',numdata_1,sheet,'D3');
```

I will appreciate if someone helps me in this regard.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the 3rd output of `xlsread` to get the raw data - the first output is just numeric. Then all of the data you read in will be in a cell array and the type doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
[numdata_1,txt,raw] = xlsread(filename,sheet,xlRange);
writecell(raw,'pp.xlsx');
```